# Fastest way to find minimum distance between points

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a set of 2D points and need to find the fastest way to figure out which pair of points has the shortest distance in the set.

What is the optimal way to do this? My approach is to sort them with quicksort and then calculate the distances. This would be O(nlogn + n) = O(nlogn).

Is it possible to do it in linear time?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you sort two dimensional data with quicksort? And how does this help finding the two closest points?

Comment: I just sort them by x coordinate. Basically it seems I implemented the algorithm explained at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_problem. First sort by x, then divide and conquer. So it seems there is no faster way.

Comment: Sorting by X is of no real value at all, since the closest points may not have close X values.  And sorting by X doesn't reduce the need to compare every point against every other point to find the closest pair.

Comment: Actually it does. Look at the Wikipedia link above and the divide and conquer solution. It is O(N log N).

Comment: The Wikipedia article says it's actually O(n log log n) if floor is a constant time operation (however, I don't think it actually is, for arbitrarily large numbers)

Comment: It looks like you are assuming quicksort is O(n*log2(n)), however quicksort's worse case is O(n^2).

Answer (score 11):

[It is actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_problem):

> The **closest pair of points problem** or **closest pair problem** is a problem of [computational geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry): given *n* points in metric space, find a pair of points with the smallest distance between them...
>
> In the computational model which assumes that the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_function) is computable in constant time the problem can be solved in O(*n* log log *n*) time. If we allow randomization to be used together with the floor function, the problem can be solved in O(*n*) time..

Answer (score -1):

If you could probe out a constant amount from each point and use iterative deepening DFS, youd never check further apart than the two closest points...and since you're not dependent on a failed pass, you'd never need to recompute the way ID DFS tends to.

Answer (score -4):

No.  Minimum distance among ALL points in **O**( *n* ^ 2 ) because you must compare every point against every other point.  Technically it's *n* * *n* / 2 because you only have to fill have to fill half the matrix.

There are faster algorithms are for finding the nearest neighbor to a given point.  Unfortunately, you have to then do this for every point to find the closest two points.

Comment: The diagram isn't an algorithm.  The Fortune Algorithm produces the diagram.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm.  I'm not sure this applies, since it partitions space rather than compares points.