# choose a point which minimizes the sum of distances between it and other points in set

Tags: algorithm

I read a [post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9750/13562) which talks about pretty much the same problem. But here I simplify the problem hoping that a concrete proof can be offered.

There is a set `A` which contains some discrete points (1-dimension), like `{1, 3, 37, 59}`. And I want to pick one point from `A` which can minimize the sum of distances between this point and others.

There might be a lot of posts out there, and my problem is just the `1-d` version of those, and I know how to prove it if `A` is not discrete, but I fail when `A` is discrete like above.

Plz offer me the answer with concrete proof, thanks.

Comment: I believe that point is called the median, or in the case of an even number of points, any point between the two mid points. In other words, in your sample, any point between 3 and 37.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

Answer (score 6):

Not a strictly (or even loosely) mathematical proof, if that is what you need, you're most likely asking in the wrong place :)

Let's call the 1D coordinate `x` and let's say raising `x` is moving to the right. The point you're looking for is `mx`.

- If `mx` has more points to the right than to the left, moving `mx` to the right will raise the distance to *the fewer points* to the left and lower it to *the more points* to the right which will lower the average distance.
- In other words, `mx` cannot have fewer points to the left than to the right, if there are, there is a way to lower the average.

The converse is also true.

If the number of elements is odd, the only point fulfilling the above requirement is the median.

If the number of elements is even, any point between the two mid elements will fulfill the condition.

Comment: This gives the median iff the distance between two elements that are next to each other according to the order of the set is equal for all pairs of neighbors. Take for example -100 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. The way I understood the question, this isn't about finding the middle element, but that which minimizes the sum of distances, which clearly wouldn't be 3 here, it would be 0.

Comment: It's clearly not 3, except it is :). At 3, the total distance is (103 + 3 + 2 + 1) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 119. At 0, the total distance is (100) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) = 128.

Comment: +1, but you have to be a bit careful about what happens as you move x over a point. For instance, if x is just to the left of the median (and the median is in the set), then moving to the right may increase the distance if you jump too far.

Answer (score 2):

Since between points the total-distance function is linear and the distance-function is continuous everywhere, the minimum must be attained at one of the points in the set. So you can restrict A to be in the given set.

Here's a graph for the total-distance function from the points {-3, 1, 2, 5} as an example:
[image: Graph of distance function]

Say there's L points to the left, and R to the right of A.

Moving one point to the right changes the distance by d * (L + 1 - R) (where d is the distance to the next point). Similarly, moving one point to the left changes the distance by d * (R + 1 - L).

The points that minimize |L-R| are where this distance is minimized. That's either the median (if it's in the set), or either of the two adjacent points to the median if it's not.

Comment: Seriously, `the distance-function is continuous everywhere` even for discrete set of points?

Comment: @Alcott sure. The distance function for a single point a is `d(x) = |x - a|` which looks like a V (and is continuous). For a set of points you add up the V's for each of the points in the set. And a finite sum of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score -1):

Considering [Fastest way to find minimum distance between points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788733/fastest-way-to-find-minimum-distance-between-points) question try to take a look to [closest pair of points problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_problem).

Comment: The problems are different. This is minimize **sum of distances** from some point (may not be in the set) to all the points in a set, the links are finding 2 points with minimum distance.